# Не видит приложение. ImportError: No module named '_django'

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-3.5

Когда запускажю `python3 manage.py runserver` , выдает в конце:

```
  File "/home/skiesx/Dropbox/projects/name_project/src/apps/urls.py", line 30, in <module>
    path('^', include('myapp.urls')),
  File "/home/skiesx/Dropbox/projects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'
```

Структура:

```
[name_project]
    ├── src
    │   ├── settings
    │   |   ├── __init__.py
    │   |   ├── _django.py
    │   ├── apps
    │   |   ├── myapp
    │   |   |   ├── ...
    │   |   |   ├── urls.py
    │   |   |   ├── ...
    │   |   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   ├── manage.py
    ├── public
    │   ├── static
    │   ├── media
    └── requirements
```

Файл `apps/urls.py` :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('^', include('myapp.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Не подключаются urls приложения myapp. Подаскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Оно вообще не видит то приложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не претендую на 100% правильность, ибо пишу по памяти, но если Вы хотите размещать приложения во вложенных папках, нужно сделать примерно следующее:

1. в папке apps создать файл `__init__.py` (можно пустой), чтобы папка могла использоваться как модуль;
2. все приложения должны быть зарегистрированы в файле `settings.py` в виде

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'apps.myapp',
      'apps.myapp2',
    ]
```

3. соответственно, в urlpatterns надо `path('^', include('myapp.urls')),` тоже заменить на `path('^', include('apps.myapp.urls')),`
4. ну и придется не забывать везде, где будете использовать Ваши приложения и их данные, дописывать `'apps.'` перед названием приложения.

Как то так...